# PHP x lines than stop

Tags: php, string

How can i only echo 5 lines?

```
<?php
$text = Here i have a long long long text about 20 lines;
echo $text; 
?>
```

So and i want something like that.->
TEXTLINE 1
TEXTLINE 2
TEXTLINE 3
TEXTLINE 4
TEXTLINE 5

And than stop.

Comment: the output is a console or a browser ?

Comment: please define "line". is line a series of characters till a /r/n character? or is it "line" what you actually see displaying on screen and what screen? or something else?

Comment: line of a <p> for example so i use this in a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for the mentioned text of Harri (at least this would be my approach):

```
$strings = explode(" ", $text);
for($i=0; $i<$your_lines; $i++) {
    echo $strings[$i] . " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Explode](https://www.php.net/explode) the string to array, then loop through the array until last line you want to print. Printh each line while looping the array.

Answer (score 1):

when you need lines (not words) use

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming the output is a web browser*, then this is a display issue, since what you are referring to as "line" depends on the width/height of the container. (It's not very clear what you try to ask)

You can set a width and height on a div using css and use overflow hidden on that to achieve a result like the one you want

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/g5Y5c/

```
.mydiv {width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;}
```